# Two submit buttons in cakephp that save contents in two different tables

Tags: cakephp

I have a schedule button and a send button. The send button directly sends the text (i.e)It saves the data in the table twilio_sent_text. What I am trying here is, when I click the schedule button the data should be saved in another table. Here is my code for the View:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('TwilioText', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Emailer','action' => 'text_sendmsg'), 
    'novalidate'
));
echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.msgSentNmbr', array(
    'type' => 'hidden', 
    'placeholder' => 'Phone', 
    'label' => false, 
    'class' => 'form-control', 
    'div' => false, 'value' => $value
));
echo $this->Form->input('TwilioSentText.msgTitle', array(
    'label' => false, 
    'class' => 'text-list', 
    'div' => false,
    'type' => 'select',                  
    'ng-options' => "key as value.textName for (key , value) in textcontents",
    'ng-change' => "textcontent = textcontents[textName].textDescription;",
    'ng-model' => "textName",'empty' => 'Content'
));
echo $this->Form->input('', array(
    'label' => false, 
    'class' => 'text-list3', 
    'div' => false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'ng-options' => "",
    'ng-change' => "",
    'ng-model' => "",
    'empty' => 'Current Deals'
));
echo $this->Form->textarea('TwilioSentText.sent_msg', array(
    'placeholder' => 'Text Content', 
    'ng-model' => 'textcontent', 
    'label' => false, 
    'id' => 'nwtext', 
    'class' => 'form-control', 
    'div' => false, 
    'value' => ''
)); 
echo $this->Form->submit('Schedule', array(
    'div'=>false, 
    'name'=>'submit',
    'url'=> array('controller'=>'Emailer','action'=>'auto_text')
)); 
echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array(
    'class' => 'btntext', 
    'div' => false
));
echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

The send button is working fine but when I click the schedule button it is performing the same action as the send button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle name of button and then use simple if to recognize which button was pressed.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('form_name'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('btn_1', array('name' => 'btn')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('btn_2', array('name' => 'btn')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

if($this->request->data['btn'] == 'btn_1') {
 // is btn1 pressed
} else {
 // btn2 pressed
}
```

Comment: This didnt work. It just displayed an error message "Undefined index TwilioText"

Comment: Yea, use $this->request->data['btn'] (without form name), sory for that miss.
I fix it in my snippet.

Comment: @Sojtin Any idea what the equivalent of this is for CakePHP 3?